# How to test list length in Drools 7.59?

Tags: drools

I'm trying to test for the length of a list of objects. I'm following the pattern that I used in older versions of Drools (7.44 and earlier), but it doesn't appear to be working anymore.

This is my rule:

```
global BookEventResult result;

rule "Person has 3 or more existing checked out books"
when
  BookEvent( type == BookEventType.BORROW )
  Person( $books: checkedOutBooks )
  ArrayList( size >= 3 ) from $books
then
  result.setSuccess(false);
  result.setReason("User has already checked out 3 books");
end
```

The Person instance I'm passing into the rules has 3 items:

```
class Person {
  List<Book> checkedOutBooks = new ArrayList<>(); // 3 Book instances in here
}
```

... and the BookEvent type is 'BORROW'. I've confirmed both with a debug session in the IDE.

The rule doesn't trigger, however.

I'm using Drools 7.59.0.Final, specifically the `drools-engine-classic` dependency (because I prefer mvel.) Also Java 17 (openjdk). Observed the same behavior in 7.50.0.Final and 7.47.0.Final; can't test 45 or 46 because of what looks like JDK incompatibility. 47 seems to be a bit iffy JDK-wise as well.

I also retested on 7.59 with JDK 11 (Eclipse Temurin AdoptOpenJDKHotspot) with the same results.

I've used this same pattern extensively over the years; this is the first time it has failed me. Have the newest versions of drools introduced some form of non-backwards compatibility here? How am I supposed to check for list length now?

---

Just for giggles, I added these two test rules to see what is going on:

```
rule "Test - No check"
when
  Person( $books: checkedOutBooks )
then
  System.out.println("Book size: " + $books.size());
  System.out.println( $books.getClass().getName() );
end

rule "Test - Exactly 3 books"
when
  Person( $books: checkedOutBooks )
  ArrayList( size == 3 ) from $books
then
  System.out.println("Three books exactly");
end
```

The first test rule printed `Book size: 3` and `java.util.ArrayList`. The second test rule didn't fire at all.

Playing one final hunch, I added this test rule:

```
rule "Test - assign to list"
when
  Person( $books: checkedOutBooks )
  $booklist: ArrayList() from $books
then
  System.out.println("booklist size: " + $booklist.size());
end
```

The rule doesn't fire at all. I tried with both `java.util.List` and `java.util.ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked around and found some working use cases with 'size' and 'List'

```
rule "Person has 3 or more existing checked out books"
when
  BookEvent( type == BookEventType.BORROW )
  $person: Person( $books: checkedOutBooks, $books.size >= 3 )
  $book1: Book() from $person.checkedOutBooks.get(0)
  $book3: Book(name == 'book3') from $person.checkedOutBooks
  $bookNames: List(size >= 3) from accumulate (Book($name: name) from $books, collectList($name)) 
then
  System.out.println("First book " + $book1);
  System.out.println("Third book " + $book3);
  System.out.println("Book names " + $bookNames);
  System.out.println("Books " + $books);
end
```

But I think your expectation is wrong because statement `from <collection>` is designed to iterate through collection, and there is no `ArrayList` element inside. Also I've tried downgrade drools down to 7.5.0.Final and behavior seems to be consistent.

Comment: `SomeType() from $foo` has always worked as a cast in the past. You'd have to do `ArrayList()` instead of `List()` because of the concrete types issue, but it's a pattern I've followed as far back as Drools 5.0 (where I had an awful ruleset that took a `Map<string, object>` as an input ... so many casts ...)

Comment: maybe you can find some working example within your previous code (you sure previously worked) and we could try it on older versions, because I thoroughly googled for any issues like this people reported, and I didn't found any

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you kindly drop the link to the example you found? I tried to search on the document but didn't find sample for size and list in condition.

Answer (score 0):

I've create a reproducer [here](https://github.com/lucamolteni/so69332256) your rule seems to be working correclty in both `7.59.0.Final` and `7.44.0.Final`.

I'm probably missing something in my reproducer, please create a PR against it or fork it in your repo accordingly.

Comment: I've actually got a project where I had this problem, but then worked around it in the main branch. I'll re-create the problem in a branch and drop a link here.

Comment: hi Luca, opened pull request which reproduces the problem. It was not working before because it checked default result value

Comment: @Mike I've tried your PR but the behaviour seems the same, can you try run it on your machine? https://github.com/lucamolteni/so69332256/pull/1#issuecomment-940882736

Comment: Hi @Luca, when I initialize the value with true, the test starts to fail, which was not so before. The rule itself behaves the same, it doesn't trigger, that is why initial value have not changed. Either I do not understand your question or it behaves different on different machines. What would you like me to run for you? What should I share?

Comment: Your reproducer fails on my machine (and it appears to have Mike's change). I am now wondering if maybe it's JDK or OS-specific. My original project with the problematic rule is [here](https://github.com/roddy/library-demo/tree/stackoverflow), but your reproducer is much simpler and probable better to investigate with.